Issue with independent metaballs in Blender
I want to create three meta balls that move independently. As someone new to both metaballs and Blender, I tackled this by creating each meta ball separately in different Blender files. Then, I used the 'append' function (*) to bring them together, each colored differently (blue, red, and green), into a new file.
Yet, an issue arises: all three balls appear red, and when I select one, all three are selected.

(*) I'm appending 3 objects

Mball
Empty
Cube

What might be causing this? Should I not use the append function and perhaps make them in the same file since they seem to be fine in independent files.
Edit: Adding screenshots for more details



What do you mean with the "Append" function? The one from the File menu where you append objects from a different file? And for the color: when the metaballs are interacting with each other cannot have different materials.

@GordonBrinkmann yes, i meant using the append option from the file menu. They aren't exactly touching but share the same space. Would that be considered an interaction? They continue to move differently (they have different empties and values) but their colour seems to be an issue

Do they merge when you move them together? If so, they interact with each other. I cannot see all the names, but metaballs belong to each other by sharing the same "family name". I see the selected one in the screenshot is named "Mball.002". All metaballs named "Mball", "Mball.001", "Mball.002" etc. share the same family and therefore they get the same material and will merge if you move them closer together.
So, if you want to give them different materials, you have to give them different names. However, this also means they will not be merging with each other - and that's what's you usually do with metaballs, so I wonder if you really want to separate them.

Thank you for your response! I want the 3 of them to move individually to show 3 different movements. I've added some layer details (probably not the right term) for all of them as well as one of them.

@Der8 I do not know why exactly you added the screenshot now since it does not give any new information which I did not already suspected in my answer - it shows they all have the same name, only distinguished by the suffix. If you want to give them different materials, give them different names... maybe in relation to the colors you want to give them "R-ball", "G-ball", "B-ball", or just "R", "G" and "B"... or "red", "green", "blue", whatever you like.
